# How to insert some field data into a data source file after reading from another text file

Tags: python, csv, text-files, calculated-field

The following script is working perfectly. It computes the percentages changes from sourcedata.txt against updatedata.txt. However, I wanted to insert into sourcedata.txt by appending the read values from the updatedata.txt.

```
s1 = open("sourcedata.txt", "r")
u1 = open("updatedata.txt", "r")

i = 0
item = 0
for line1 in s1:
i += 1
st1 = list(line1.split()[1::1]) #converting str to list
st1_a,st1_b= [int(x) for x in st1]  #converting str to int

for line2 in u1:
    item += 1
    st2 = list(line2.split()[1::1])
    st2_a,st2_b= [int(x) for x in st2]
    print ("Item%s " % item + "%s" % st1 + " -> " + "%s" % st2)

    print (f" Change: { round(((st2_a - st1_a)/st1_a)*100,2)}%  { round(((st2_b - st1_b)/st1_b)*100,2)} ")  #you can make seprate function to calculate to percentage change , round for rounding the number
    print()
# closing files
s1.close()                                  
u1.close()
```

Current Output and Wanted Modification Result

```
Current Output:
 Item1 ['10', '30'] -> ['120', '375']
 Change: 1100.0%  1150.0 
 Item2 ['10', '30'] -> ['545', '550']
 Change: 5350.0%  1733.33 
 Item3 ['10', '30'] -> ['750', '690']
 Change: 7400.0%  2200.0 
 
sourcedata.txt <- Initial Data File
 item1 10 30 1 1
 item2 25 50 2 2
 item3 50 75 3 3

updatedata.txt <- File that contains update
 item1 120 375
 item2 545 550
 item3 750 690

sourcedata.txt <- This is the updated file after running the script
 item1 10 30 120 375   <- replace 1 1 with 120 375
 item2 25 50 545 550   <- replace 2 2 with 545 550
 item3 50 75 750 690   <- replace 3 3 with 750 690
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure about the calculations as I cannot execute your program, but I think I can help you with the output you want. As you showed, you want to read two files and append the columns of the "source" file to the "updated" file. This can be done by adapting your code with this:

```
s1 = open("sourcedata.txt", "r")
u1 = open("updatedata.txt", "r")

# Create list of lines from source file
source_items = []
for line1 in s1:
    columns = list(line1.split()) # split line into list of columns
    first_column = [columns[0]] # leave as str
    other_columns = [int(x) for x in columns[1:]] #converting str to int
    all_columns = first_column + other_columns

    source_items.append(all_columns)  #converting str to int

# Close source file
s1.close()  

print(source_items)

# Create list of lines from update file
update_items = []
for line2 in u1:
    columns = list(line2.split()) # split line into list of columns
    first_column = [columns[0]] # leave as str
    other_columns = [int(x) for x in columns[1:]] #converting str to int
    all_columns = first_column + other_columns
    update_items.append(all_columns)

# Close update file
u1.close()

print(update_items)

# Copy values from update to source
for i in range(len(source_items)):
    source_items[i][-2] = update_items[i][-2] # -2 means second to last element of list
    source_items[i][-1] = update_items[i][-1] # -1 means last element

print(source_items)


# Convert lists back to string
write_lines = []
for i in source_items:
    join_rows = [str(r) for r in i] 
    write_lines.append(' '.join(join_rows))

write_lines = '\n'.join(write_lines)

print(write_lines)
 
s1 = open("sourcedata.txt", "w")
s1.writelines(write_lines)
```

The outputs are the following:

Source list:

```
[['item1', 10, 30, 1, 1], ['item2', 25, 50, 2, 2], ['item3', 50, 75, 3, 3]]
```

Updated list:

```
[['item1', 120, 375], ['item2', 545, 550], ['item3', 750, 690]]
```

Updated source list:

```
[['item1', 10, 30, 120, 375], ['item2', 25, 50, 545, 550], ['item3', 50, 75, 750, 690]]
```

Values that are written back to file:

```
item1 10 30 120 375
item2 25 50 545 550
item3 50 75 750 690
```

Comment: How to retain the item? I tried your snippet and the sourcedata is updated however, the item1, item2, item3 is deleted.

Comment: You're right! The first column was removed when reading the file. Now it should work.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. I was working on it on a different approach. This one is a lot better and more readable.

Comment: I made a repeat run of the script. During the first run, sourcedata.txt is updated. After making a second run, it emptied.

Comment: What do you mean with emptied? If you run the script twice, on the second run should change nothing with the same input files. Do you use another file on the second run?

Comment: Its all working now. I was running on debug mode. That could be the reason perhaps.